# How to destroy/make a file unreadable programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net

While I was doing some stuff with vb programming, I have come across a pdf file that is corrupted and unreadable. Now, I just wondered if is it possible to create an unreadable file programmatically?

I actually have it, when I open the file it says "There was an error opening this document.  There was a problem reading this document(14)"

Now, what I want to achieve is on how to "destroy" a file. Any kind of file. Say I have a working pdf file which can be opened by Adobe Reader, how to make it "unreadable" to Adobe Reader so that when I open it, it will show some messagebox saying "error opening file" or something like that.. here's an example [link](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_2IcDDSGLLnc/SaOxODi5mWI/AAAAAAAAAp8/GobgkUNUuzQ/s400/ErrorReadingFromFile.jpg)

Comment: You cannot make a text file unreadable. Why don't you just delete the file.

Comment: @ david sorry, maybe I made a wrong example, wait I'll edit my question

Comment: A file is only *corrupt* to a specific reader which cannot make sense of it. Using notepad, you can open almost anything.

Comment: Sure. Just throw some garbage in a file, change its extension to ".pdf" and try opening it with acrobat reader. "Unreadable" files are always unreadable in a certain context. Meaning that the application handling that file type is unable to make any sense of the file. It doesn't mean the file can't actually be read. That only happens when you have insufficient permissions to read the file or if your OS is unable to read the file (e.g. from a defective harddrive).

Comment: Well, you could scramble the Byte Stream and really confuse the system as to what the file is, but plain text will still open in just about anything.

Comment: I'm triggered by the "access denied" in the screenshot. Have you considered revoking access to the file using ACL? While it's not better than encryption, it still can be an option.

Comment: @ dirk yes I am aware of it, but say we have a pdf file how to make it corrupted without changing it's extension?

Comment: I edited my question into a more specific one.. if you want I can upload the pdf file for you to see. I just want to know if it is possible to create something like that, programmatically, with any existing file.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this as I think it is a valid question (albeit the wording could be improved, so I have edited it)

Answer (score 4):

Technically, short of hardware error, there is no such thing as "unreadable". A file contains bytes. It's readable. However, a PDF-reader expects those bunch of bytes to have a specific format. If it does not, the program cannot make a valid pdf from it.

Imagine a piece of paper for a actor to read. If you ripped half the page of, the other page is far from unreadable. It's just that the actor will complain, that he won't play his role on only half a script.

You can overwrite the bytes in a file. If your file is a 500 bytes file that can be interpreted as a pdf, you can instead make it a file with 2 bytes that say "FU". Then it's a two byte file. The pdf reader will complain. If you open it in a text editor, it will read "FU". One programs garbage is another programs data.

Comment: +1 that analogy sure was clear. That was what I thought too. This is the concept I have in mind, it's just that I want to convert it to a program. I'm not yet well versed with programming yet (only 6 months of experience so far). Now upon reading this I just thought my question is almost pointless XD

Comment: But maybe I can still do something with the file, like read it to the point where it breaks..

Answer (score 1):

What made the pdf unreadable is the file was not in the format the reader expects it to be in. For a basic txt file there is no format to follow, whatever bytes are there is what is displayed on screen. You will likely get gibberish, but it would still open.

To "Break" the file you would have to break the filesystem. There may be ways to do it but you can't do it with managed code, you will need to invoke native API calls to get to the raw filesystem to do it and you would need to parse the filesystem yourself, windows does not provide anything like that. Perhaps look for a open source hex editor that can read the MRR to help figure out which calls you would need to make. (IMPORTANT NOTE: if you try this you will likely make your computer un-bootable during your experimentation, backup all of your files before you start playing with the filesystem structure)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the contents of the file for others, you could simply encrypt the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to encrypt the file:

```
byte[] keySalt = new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 };  

Encrypt("original.txt",  "encrypted.txt", "myPassword", keySalt);  

public static void Encrypt(string fileIn, string fileOut, string pass, byte[] keySalt)  
{  
   PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(pass, keySalt);  

   Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();  
   alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);  
   alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);  

   using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))  
   {  
      using (FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))  
      {  
         using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsIn, Encoding.Default))  
         {  
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))  
            {  
              int len = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;  
              cs.Write(br.ReadBytes(len), 0, len);  
              cs.FlushFinalBlock();  
            }  
         }  
       }  
   }  
}
```